# "Device not recognized" with USB hard drive

Tags: windows-7, usb-storage

I have a problem with an LG external hard drive. Every time I connect it to a PC or a laptop the following error message appears:

> "USB Device not Recognized. One of the
>   USB devices attached to this computer
>   has malfunctioned, and Windows does
>   not recognize it."

The cable is connected and the power LED is on.

How can I troubleshoot or fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the drive powered by the USB bus or by an external power adaptor? If it's powered by the USB bus it should have been provided with a special USB cable having two connectors at one end. This cable should be used with both connectors plugged into the computer so that it can get twice the power from the USB bus. If it's not getting enough power, it may not be able to operate properly.

If it's an external power supply then I'm with edusysadmin - try connecting the drive direct to a computer to check it's working OK.

Comment: interesting, can you name any models like that? 2 usb ports for extra power?

Comment: @barlop - We use a Transcend 2.5" USB enclosure at work that has a USB Y cable to get extra power....most of the time we find that its not needed though.  http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817349001

Answer (score 0):

It's either the hard disk drive within the enclosure that has failed, or the enclosure has failed. Take the drive out of the external enclosure and test it directly into your computer.

If computers still don't recognize the drive, the drive has failed. Otherwise the enclosure is the issue.